# How to get data from calling page while in Ion Modal

Tags: javascript, meteor, ionic-framework, meteor-blaze, meteoric

On one of my pages (which has

```
<button class="button button-small button-balanced" data-ion-modal="reviewPopup">
    leave review
</button>
```

in that Modal I have a form that, when I click a button for, should send data to the server from both the Modal and the template from template a. I can get data from the form in the Modal just fine, but I can't access any data from the calling page (specifically I need the `_id`). Calling `Template.parentData` just returns null.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of triggering the modal from the template using `data-ion-modal="reviewPopup"`, you can trigger the Modal from your button event, for example -

```
Template.templateName.events({
  'click #review-popup': function() {
     //capture data from parent template first
     //....
     var parentDataContext = {some data}

     IonModal.open("reviewPopup", parentDataContext);
  }
})
```

After the modal opens, the parent data can be accessed using `this` in the modal helpers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Template.parentData (from the modal) will be returning either the body template, or another top level template specific to the meteoric framework.  Either way, 
If you were using a different framework where you specifically add the modal template to the page somewhere I'd suggest passing in _id as a template parameter.

But with meteoric, as far as I know, you can't do that - so you may have to use something with global scope.

If you are using a router, and have the _id as part of the route, get it from there (e.g.  FlowRouter.current().params ).

Or just use the simplest option and use a Session variable.  Set it in a onRendered function, access it in the Modal's event functions